# FacialFeatures is not a Graphics primitive or directive

Tags: graphics

This is my code, and he work perfectly, except "Graphics", its not showing the rectangle on my face. The message is: FacialFeatures is not a Graphics primitive or directive. Can someone help me? I think its easy to solve, but I don't know how. Tks

```
    Dynamic[image = CurrentImage[]; 
     faces = FacialFeatures[image]; 
     Show[{image, Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Red, Thick}], FaceForm[], 
      Rectangle@@@faces}]}]]
```

Comment: Does this work if you do it without the `Dynamic`?

Comment: `Rectangle @@@ faces` is not doing what you think it is doing. Check it out. And ditch the dynamic when debugging. (tested in 11.3 on Mac)

Comment: Jason B. Yes, He's take a picture but whitout the Graphics (rectangle). The message is the same.

Comment: user6014. The message is the same. I don't know if that is a configuration problem.